# Who are the "soldiers" running around the new Avengers facility at the end of "Avengers Age of Ultron"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

At the end of *Avengers Age of Ultron* , we see the new upstate New York Avengers faculty.  There are a whole lot of soldier-looking dudes running around in formation.  Who are these guys?!?  SHIELD has been discredited and disbanded at this point...

Per the wiki at [Fandom](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/New_Avengers_Facility),

> Many of the staff are former S.H.I.E.L.D. agents, such as Maria Hill or Nick Fury... The base is used for scientific research, **military training**, weapons development and the New Avengers program. Vehicles and aircraft such as the Quinjet are also stationed at the facility (emphasis added).

...but it seems like an awful big and militaristic staff to support a few Avengers and a couple of aircraft.  Who is getting all this "military training"?

Comment: "[Avengers recruits](http://www.joblo.com/movie-news/new-set-footage-and-images-from-joss-whedons-avengers-age-of-ultron-186)"

Comment: From hat we see in Spiderman: Homecoming, it appears to mostly be a Tony Stark show. I'm willing to bet these are Stark Industries PMC-types. After all, he can't guard everything with robots. That's how you get Ultron.

Comment: Two options, one inspired by Valorum link:  1) SHIELD agents maintaining a low profile prior to SHIELD being reinstated after the Sokovia Accords; 2) Department of Damage Control...